# ggplot2 "geom_path requires the following missing aesthetics"

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've been busy building a scatterplot of shot chart data, and want to essentially draw a basketball court behind it. I have seen this done on other stackoverflow questions, but even when replicating the code I cannot get mine to work.

I can run my scatterplot seperately just fine, and the way it's set up now is perfect. I can run all the geom_path() statements separately just fine if I add a
`"ggplot(data=data.frame(x=1,y=1),aes(x,y))+`
to the top portion of the geom_path statements, but when I try and put these together I am getting an error

The reason that I have all the inherit.aes=FALSE in all my statements is because I was certain that the "object "x.coord" not found" error that I was getting prior to this one was due to geom_path statements inheriting from the ggplot statement.

```
chart.player <- ggplot(player5, aes(x =x.coord,y =y.coord , col = pts_att, size = log)) +
  geom_point() + scale_colour_gradient("Points/Attempt", low = "green", high="red") + coord_fixed() +

  ###outside box:
  geom_path(data=outside_box,inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  ###solid FT semicircle above FT line:
  geom_path(data=ft_semi_above,aes(x=x,y=y),inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  ###dashed FT semicircle below FT line:
  geom_path(data=ft_semi_below,aes(x=x,y=y),linetype='dashed',inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  ###key:
  geom_path(data=key,inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  ###box inside the key:
  geom_path(data=box_key,inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  ###restricted area semicircle:
  geom_path(data=ra_semi,aes(x=x,y=y),inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  ###halfcourt semicircle:
  geom_path(data=half_semi,aes(x=x,y=y),inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  ###rim:
  geom_path(data=rim,aes(x=x,y=y),inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  ###backboard:
  geom_path(data=backboard,lineend='butt',inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  ###three-point line:
  geom_path(data=threept,aes(x=x,y=y),inherit.aes=FALSE)

plot(chart.player)
Error: geom_path requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Comment: You may want to add the aes values to geom_path() with no aes values

Comment: Hey @user2510479, that actually worked out great. Now the plots are working! However, I noticed that now my "size" legend is slightly off and showing different thicknesses of black bars instead of circle size (representing frequency). Hopefully I should be able to figure that one out though!

Thanks!